# how to make the tab visible for other users

Tags: community, administration

Household information must only be visible to the director and staff.

Adoption requests are only visible by staff and directors.

Comment: Ok on review it is a different question but this is standard Salesforce functionality which you can learn by using the Admin Workbook https://resources.docs.salesforce.com/sfdc/pdf/forcecom_workbook.pdf

Answer (score 0):

In the profile you can also set the accessibility of the objects within Salesforce and make the Objects only visible to users with certain profiles.

Remove Read permission on an object from a profile and users assigned to that profile are no longer able to view any data from that object or even see that it exists.

[image: Object settings]

You can hide the Tabs by using different profiles for the users and then in the Administer>Manage Users>Profiles>Object Settings select if a specific object's tab is visible or hidden from that Profile.
[image: Tab Settings]

Comment: i am not asking about tab. i am asking about a field and its data

Comment: That is not what your question is asking. Are you asking about the Objects as well as they can also be set at profile level? I'll add that in the answer.